# how to add logo to navigation bar in ios xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

In my project I want to add logo to navigation bar. In android by using custom renderer I have placed the logo to navigation bar. But i don't know how to set the logo in navigation bar at globally in ios xamarin forms. Anyone give suggestion how to solve this.

I have tried like this,

`NavigationPage.SetTilteIcon(this, "icon.png");` // But image is not display

[Icon placement Reference Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eplvl.png)

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: Put some screenshot of your app where you want to display the title

Comment: What is the code you are trying to do so. Are you using master detail page?

Comment: No, I am not using master detail page.I am only using navigation page to navigate the next views

Comment: Can you edit you question with some code you are trying else it is difficult to  understand and answer

Comment: I have added the code

Answer (score 0):

You can try by setting the icon as:

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new FirstPageName() { Icon="icon.png"});
```

While navigating to another page you can write this as:

```
this.Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPageName() { Icon="icon.png"});
```

Make sure you have the icon image in iOS project folder.

Comment: I want to set the logo at navigation bar globally. Any renderer for achieve that?

Comment: I used your suggestion code, but icon is not shown. @Himanshu Dwivedi

Answer (score 0):

You can try custom renderer for a single page. But we can't set it at globally. Because in iOS every ViewController has a NavigationItem, we should set it when we need.

Here is some code about how to set NavigationItem in page renderer:

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

    UIView leftView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, 100, 40));
    UIImageView imgView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromBundle("icon.png"));
    imgView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 5, 30, 30);
    leftView.AddSubview(imgView);

    UILabel label = new UILabel(new CGRect(30, 10, 70, 20));
    label.Text = "page Title";
    leftView.AddSubview(label);

    //add event
    UITapGestureRecognizer tap = new UITapGestureRecognizer((sender) =>
    {

    });
    leftView.AddGestureRecognizer(tap);
    leftItem = new UIBarButtonItem(leftView);

    NavigationController.TopViewController.NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem(leftItem, true);
}
```

Please notice that put this image source in iOS's project.

Also if you do want to show this icon image in each page. Try to create a base page and construct this renderer for it. Then let your page inherit from it.